# MySQL status swap for bitwise operators

Tags: php, mysql, replace, status, swap

I am looking for a solution/best practice to do a swap of values for a status flag.

The status INT(3) in mysql has a few values, and I'd like to be able to swap the LIVE and NOT_LIVE values around, without interrupting what other bitwise values are in there.

If it was a flag field, as in 0 or 1, it is easy:

```
'status' NOT 'status'
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could do a swap based on two values (x, y) - without too much code-logic, like the code above. Of course I may be dreaming, and just have to revert to a SELECT query, and if statement and an UPDATE...

any ideas?

Comment: I think we really need more examples here to be able to help you properly

Comment: Yes, more examples would be welcome. For instance, what are the different possible values for `status` and what would be the expected outcome? See my updated answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your values are 1 and 2, but you want bit-style flipping? that won't work because 1 and 2 have different bits set!

try this:

```
UPDATE table SET status = CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by "swap[ping] the `LIVE` and `NOT_LIVE` values" ? If `LIVE` is a bit that is set/unset then what you are looking for is a bitwise NAND. For instance, if its value is 8 and you want to *unset* it

```
UPDATE table SET status = status &~ 8
```

It will unset the bit whose value is 8. If `LIVE` and `NOT_LIVE` are two different bits then you'll need to set one (OR) and unset the other (NAND). Here I'll remove `NOT_LIVE` (4) while setting `LIVE` (8)

```
UPDATE table SET status = (status &~ 4) | 8
```

If `status` can **only have two values** then what you need is add those two values then substract `status`. For instance, if the two values are 1 and 2

```
UPDATE table SET status = (1 + 2) - status
```

which of course you can write

```
UPDATE table SET status = 3 - status
```

Note that this will fail if `status` takes any other value. You can avoid that by only changing `status` if it's one of the two.

```
UPDATE table SET status = 3 - status WHERE status IN (1, 2)
```

In this case, if `status` is neither `LIVE` or `NOT_LIVE`, it won't be changed.

Comment: By swapping I mean, if the status is LIVE then I'd like it to change to be NOT_LIVE. 

So:

    LIVE = 1
    NOT_LIVE = 2

So if the 'status' = 1, then it changes to 2. And if it is 2, then it changes to 1. As I said the status NOT status just flips the values, there is not find/if statement/update - it just flips the values...

Answer (score 0):

You need the [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html) here:

```
UPDATE table SET status = CASE
    WHEN status = 1 THEN 2
    WHEN status = 2 THEN 3
    ELSE 1
END CASE
```

Alternately, you can use the [if statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if-statement.html), if you like:

```
UPDATE table SET status =
    IF     status = 1 THEN 2
    ELSEIF status = 2 THEN 3
    ELSE   1
END IF
```